# BMI in Python with file input

Tags: python

I have an assignment which I can't get through. I'm a beginner at programming and I want to understand it better for my course. Can someone help me? I really don't understand it.

This is the assignment:

The BMI is defined as weight/length2. A BMI between 18,5 and 25 as ideal and considers people with such a BMI healthy.
The program receives input consisting of two persons with their name, sex, length and weight.

```
    Jack Johnson M 1.78 83
    Maria Miller V 1.69 60
```

Process this input into structured data. To achieve this, use an useful class with useful methods to enhance the structure of the program. Use this structured data to print for each person: an appropriate style of address, surname, the BMI and a statement whether this is considered healthy or not.

Example:

```
    Mr. Johnson’s BMI is 26.2 and is unhealthy.
    Mrs. Miller’s BMI is 21.0 and is healthy.
```

This is what I have:

```
    class Person(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.last_name = last_name
            self.sex = sex
            self.length = length    #m
            self.weight = weight    #kg

        def bmi(self):
            return self.weight / self.length ** 2

        def healthy(self):
            if BODYMASSINDEX <25 and BODYMASSINDEX>18.5:
                person = healthy
            else:
                person = unhealthy
            return person
```

---

```
    from person import Person

    file = open("BMIInput.txt")
    invoer = file.read().splitlines()
    details_person1 = invoer[0].split()
    details_person2 = invoer[1].split()

    person1 = Person(details_person1)
    person2 = Person(details_person2)


    print "%s's BMI is %.1f and is %s" %(person1.name, person1.bmi, person1.healthy)
```

The BMI Input is:

```
    Jack Johnson    M   1.78    83
    Maria Miller    V   1.69    60
```

Comment: Help us understand what is your question and where are you stuck?

Comment: @downshift 
My question is that when I do person1 = Person(details_person1) it shows: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) 
How can I get the details_person1 in person1?

Comment: You don't have any arguments in Person.__init__ and you are passing an array

Answer (score 0):

Add the arguments to the init

```
    class Person(object):
        def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, sex, length, weight):
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.last_name = last_name
            self.sex = sex
            self.length = length    #m
            self.weight = weight    #kg

        def bmi(self):
            return self.weight / self.length ** 2

        def healthy(self):
            if BODYMASSINDEX <25 and BODYMASSINDEX>18.5:
                person = healthy
            else:
                person = unhealthy
            return person
```

Then unpack the list:

```
from person import Person

file = open("BMIInput.txt")
invoer = file.read().splitlines()
details_person1 = invoer[0].split()
details_person2 = invoer[1].split()

person1 = Person(*details_person1)
person2 = Person(*details_person2)


print "%s's BMI is %.1f and is %s" %(person1.name, person1.bmi, person1.healthy)
```

Comment question about int, float is more what you need:

Just to solve the issue this is not clean nor the right way but it will work:
Inside the init

```
self.length = float(length) if type(length) != float else length
self.weight = float(weight) if type(weight) != float else weight
```

What I'd do is :

```
details_person1 = invoer[0].split()
details_person1[3] = float(details_person1[3])
details_person1[4] = float(details_person1[4])
```

The same thing with details_person2

Comment: Thanks! Now I have an issue with that there's a float required and it only gives strings. How can I change some of the parts in the string in ints?

Comment: For calculating BMI you should convert to `float` rather than `int`, especially for height. Also `int("1.5")` does not work. `int(float("1.5"))` works but gives only `1` which will lead to incorrect estimation of BMI. Best would be to use `float(length)`. Also better to use term `height` rather than `length` which is used only for very small children.

Comment: Yes you are right. He asked for int but float is wha he needs.

Comment: @Gabriëlla if this is the answer you wanted can you please mark it as solution ;-)